# Show another attribute value on model rules error message

Tags: php, yii

I validate a new entry through a checksum which is md5() of all entries to see if the entry already exists and that is working just fine, but for the rules message I want to display the entry "name" instead of the unique attribute as following:

```
public function rules() {
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), array(
        array('checksum', 'unique', 'message' => 'Store ' . $this->name . 'already exists on the database.'),
    ));
}
```

rules function always has  $this->name as null. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`CUniqueValidator` supports a custom `{value}` placeholder in the error message for this exact situation, but unfortunately that maps to the value of the attribute being validated (checksum) so you can't use take advantage of it to display the name.

Additionally, when `rules()` is called by the framework the current instance is still empty, so `$this->name` as written above will always have the default value for the `name` attribute -- usually `null`.

The only way to get what you want is to extend `CUniqueValidator`, perhaps like this:

```
class ExtendedUniqueValidator extends CUniqueValidator
{
    public $additionalPlaceholders;

    protected function addError($object,$attribute,$message,$params=array())
    {
        $params['{attribute}']=$object->getAttributeLabel($attribute);

        $additional = array_filter(
            array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->additionalPlaceholders)));
        foreach ($additional as $attributeName) {
            $params['{'.$attributeName.'}'] = $object->$attributeName;
        }

        $object->addError($attribute,strtr($message,$params));
    }
}
```

You can then define the validation rule with

```
'additionalPlaceholders' => 'name', // comma-separated list
'message' => 'Store {name} already exists on the database.',
```

Answer (score 1):

The object that is being validated is not accessible in the rules function, instead of this the validators in Yii use a placeholder mechanism.

I think the correct way to get the behaviour you want would be to extend the uniqueValidator to include the object name in a new or existing placeholder.